# Java Quickly web applicatoin deployment practices

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

Currentyl i am working on a Java Web Application something simple JSF + Spring + Hibernate textbook application architecture, but i find my self losting time on uploading my WAR into production every time i have to do it and also in updating MySQL scripts, so

is there any good practice to deployed Java Web Application quickly?

**Edit**

This is the current Process:

1. I work on localhost where i quickly
   deploy with eclipse
2. If everything work fines i export a WAR with eclipse
3. Upload this WAR through FTP into (hosted) production server
4. Move this into tomcat webapps

Thanks.

Tip. I'm Using eclipse as my IDE and ain't using Maven nor Ant

Comment: What exactly do you want to do: Upload to the production server after you've successfully changed the application, or deploy to the local server for testing?  Is there any particular reason you don't use build tools like Maven or Ant?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you develop JSF apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446694/how-do-you-develop-jsf-apps)

Comment: i want a production deployment not a local developement deploy

Comment: @Matt: I suppose not: @Necronet asked about deployment to a production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of tools you can use to automate the build and deployment process:

Compile application => deploy to local server => execute unit- and integration tests => upload WAR file to web server if all local tests pass -- this is exactly the kind of functionality that Maven and Ant were invented for!
If you want to get rid of the tedious manual work involved in these tasks, perhaps checking them out once more is not such a bad idea.

Also, there are more advanced Continuous Integration solutions, like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), which help you to better integrate source code management and deployment processes.

But none of those will speed up data delivery.

It seems like your most pressing concern is to find a provider to make your internet connection faster: However you manage your build process, uploading the content to the server will quite probably be the most time-consuming part.

Comment: For WAR deployments the contents of the WAR file tend to change slowly (lots of static jars).  rsync is very good for these kinds of things.

Comment: well is not the provider what i'm concern is more about to automate the steps above describe...

Answer (score 1):

The single most important thing is being able to script the stuff, so you can let the computer automate it.

You may be able to get Netbeans to create build scripts for your eclipse projects so you can just run ant to create your war.  If not, keep doing it manually.

Then you need to script the ftp-session.  That is easy - many scriptable programs exist (or you can just use a modern Norton Commander clone supporting ftp), so script it.

Then you need to script the MySQL-script changes.  This is not easy to suggest, as you did not mention what needs to be done, but you can probably get very far with a Perl script or perhaps a small stand-alone PHP snippet expanding a macro.

THen you need to collect all the steps in a single script you can then easily invoke...

(or you could just figure out how to talk to the Tomcat administrative console which allows you to update WAR files remotely - but that may not be feasible or I would have expected you to do so already)